# Searching within a list/array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've got a list, and in this list I store multiple arrays with 2 strings (title and message).

I want to be able to search for the title and **if** that title exists I want the program to output the entire array (title and message).

How can I do this?

As you can see down below it is case #2 I need help with :)

```
List<string[]> loggBoken = new List<string[]>();
case 1:

     string[] post = new string[2];
     post[0] = Console.ReadLine();
     post[1] = Console.ReadLine();
     loggBoken.Add(post);

case 2:
    **search title**
    **go through the list**
    **if title exists, write out the entire array**
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Title"? The first element of the array?

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry if I was not clear @IanH.

Comment: How does your list look like?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? @HillaryClintonEmailRemover

Comment: @Patrik Could you elaborate what you are asking

Comment: I am sorry if you do not understand what I am asking, phrasing myself correctly is still hard as I am new to programming. What I am asking is, how can I search for an element(the title) inside my list @L.B

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
string title = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (string[] arr in loggBroken)
{
     if (arr[0] == title) Array.ForEach(arr, s => Console.WriteLine(s));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And I do apologize if I explained my issue badly.

Answer (score 0):

The linq approach would be:

```
// find the array that on the first position contains your title in question
string[] match = loggBokken.Find(x=>x[0].Contains("your title"));
// print joining the content of the array separated by a space
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", match));
```

Comment: @LePelican You are welcome. You actually wrote the entire algorithm in normal language. Next time try to take this as your lead and try to put your words into code: `for` `if`... please don't forget to mark the answer that helped you. –